# Android gradle test tasks

Tags: android, android-testing

Can someone explain the **main** differences between these types of Android gradle tasks?

> - check - Runs all checks.
> - connectedAndroidTest - Installs and runs the tests for Build 'debug' on connected devices.
> - connectedCheck - Runs all device checks on currently connected devices.
> - deviceCheck - Runs all device checks using Device Providers and Test Servers.

E.g. if I run `connectedAndroidTest` and `connectedCheck`, it seems, that everything will be the same -> my test classes are called (on the device or emulator).

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Difference between different Android gradle tasks is as follows: (Ref: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide)

- check - uses Lint to run checks. These checks include layout issues, manifest errors etc. For more detail refer http://tools.android.com/tips/lint
- connectedCheck - uses connectedAndroidTest - Runs all checks/tests that requires a connected device or emulator. Thus, connectedAndroidTest and connectedCheck run same tests.
- deviceCheck - Run checks only using APIs to connect to remote devices.

Comment: I don't quite get it. What is `deviceCheck` actually doing? The explanation seems blurry for me.